# laravel Guzzle post array of data

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Good Day Can someone help me in posting array of data using guzzle, i've followed the documentation guzzle documentation and i dont know what am missing.

Routes: sync.php

```
 $api->version('v1', [
 'prefix' => 'api/v1',

],
$api->group([
    'prefix' => 'sync'

], function ($api) {
    $api->post('/accounts', 'App\Http\Controllers\SyncController@sync_accounts');

    $api->get('/updateaccount', 'App\Http\Controllers\SyncController@updateaccounts');

});
]);
```

Controller: SyncController

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  public function updateaccounts()
{
   $data = array('listid' => 'ListID',
     'Name'=> 'Name',
     'parentname'=> 'ParentRefFullName',
     'fullname'=> 'FullName');

   $http_call = new Client(['base_uri' => URL_CLOUD]);
   $res = $http_call->post('sync/accounts/', [json_encode($data)]);
   dd($res);
}

public function sync_accounts(Request $patch, $id)
{
    $data = $patch->getContent();
    return $data;
}
```

my problem here is

"error": {
"message": "Client error: POST http://.../api/v1/sync/accounts/ resulted in a 405 Method Not Allowed response:\n{\"error\":{\"message\":\"405 Method Not Allowed\",\"status_code\":405}}\n",
"code": 405,
"status_code": 500
}

Answer (score 1):

`Http 405` means that you are firing the wrong request to that endpoint get -> post or posting to get.

Your url seems to have a `v1` which is not defined as prefix so if u try this url instead:

`baseURL/sync/accounts`

Comment: sorry forgot to add

Comment: so my sync logic is wrong, first i call a function which is get method then i will call an api which it needs to get all the datas then compare and if not exist it will post to create the data.